# Tracking another drone with Opencv and Pixhawk2

Tags: c++, px4

I am working in a UAV-Team and my task is following and locking another UAV autonomously. I coded my opencv part  and I used background substitution method and several filters. I can get absolute result from  my code (like to forward go left , go right). My question is how can I send this result to the UAV's motors. How can I communicate with my UAV with C++? I've read lots of documentation from ardupilot, ardurov, opencv and pixhawk. But still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your microprocessor(i.e rasberry Pi) with pixhawk ans use mavlink communication protocols to send command here is [link](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink.html) 
And you can use [dronekit](https://dev.px4.io/en/robotics/dronekit.html) also to do that.

Comment: Is  set_rc_channel_pwm() function in MAVLINK safe? Because giving some instructions to pwm usually damages the engine.

Comment: Yes RC is safe but applying directly may cause trouble.

Comment: Sir may you give a specific function that i can use; my bachelor is computer science and really doesn't understand about communication issues. I can take x and y coordinates by using OpenCV (from the object should i track) and my middle point of my frame is set as (0,0) so. if the coordinate +,+ region. I want to set my motors direction to +,+ region. But which function should I use?
I am using MAVLINK and ArduSub as firmware.